# VBA un-protect sheet, run sub, then re-protect sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my issue, I have subs that work when I tested them with the sheet unlocked, but when I locked the sheet to protect certain cells from being selected or deleted/altered, the subs error out. So I need to add a part to my sub that unlocks, runs the main code, then re-locks the sheet.

I am looking for something like this

```
Sub Example ()
Dim sample as range
set sample as range("A3:Z100")
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
UN-PROTECT CODE
'Existing sub code here
RE-PROTECT CODE
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am however unaware on what the code to achieve this should look like. I have tried researching and all I found was incomplete code that based on the comments, didn't work all the time. I did find a suggestion to upon error, have an error handler re-protect the sheet, but not sure how to write this either. Any suggestions?

Oh, and the people who will be using this sheet will not have access to the sheet password. I plan to have the module its self password protected and the subs attached to buttons. So placing the Sheet unlock password in the sub would be ok if it is needed.

Comment: If you use the macro recorder and then protect & unprotect sheets, it will show you the code.

Comment: That did the trick after I added the password to the code so it wouldn't ask for it, then added an event handler, then just Call'ed the sub(s) as needed. Please post an answer so that I can give credit where it is due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my original comment as an answer.

If you use the macro recorder and then protect & unprotect sheets, it will show you the code.

EDIT: Added the below.

If you attempt to unprotect a sheet that is not protected you will get an error. I use this function to test if a sheet is protected, store the result in a `Boolean` variable and then test the variable to see if a) the sheet must be unprotected before writing to it and b) to see if the sheet should be protected at the end of the proc.

```
Public Function SheetIsProtected(sheetToCheck As Worksheet) As Boolean
    SheetIsProtected = sheetToCheck.ProtectContents
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to remove passwords? This worked for me

```
Sub macroProtect1()

Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="abc" 

'Enable error-handling routine for any run-time error
On Error GoTo ErrHandler   

'this code will run irrespective of an error or Error Handler
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = UCase("hello")

'this code will give a run-time error, because of division by zero. The worksheet will remain unprotected in the absence of an Error Handler. 
Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) = 5 / 0

'this code will not run, because on encountering the above error, you go directly to the Error Handler 
Sheet1.Cells(3, 1) = Application.Max(24, 112, 66, 4)

Sheet1.Protect Password:="abc" 

ErrHandler:
  Sheet1.Protect Password:="abc" 

End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work for me. But it did help me write the ErrorHandler.

Comment: @proxy156 did you try it without the Password portion? That is option, and assumes you have a password.

Answer (score 1):

had a similar problem and found this code on the web:
    Sub protectAll()
        Dim myCount
        Dim i
        myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
        Sheets(1).Select
        For i = 1 To myCount
            ActiveSheet.Protect "password", true, true
            If i = myCount Then
                End
            End If
            ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Next i
    End Sub

```
Sub Unprotect1()
    Dim myCount
    Dim i
    myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(1).Select
        For i = 1 To myCount
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
            If i = myCount Then
            End
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that it is designed to protect / unprotect all sheets in the workbook, and works fine. Apologies, and respect, to the original author, I can't remember where I found it (But I don't claim it)...

Comment: You can loop through the worksheets directly without needing the `myCount` or the `If i = myCount Then` code.

Answer (score 0):

The most common object that is **Protected** is the Worksheet Object  This make it possible to preserve formulas by **Locking** the cells that contain them.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    sh.Unprotect
        '   DO YOUR THING
    sh.Protect
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my very simple technique for situations that don't require a password (which are most situations that I run into):

```
Dim IsProtected As Boolean

IsProtected = SomeWkSh.ProtectContents: If IsProtected Then SomeWkSh.Unprotect

'Do stuff on unprotected sheet...

If IsProtected Then SomeWkSh.Protect
```

You can, of course, simplify the syntax a bit by using a **With SomeWkSh** statement but if the "Do stuff..." part refers to properties for methods of a larger, spanning **With** statement object, then doing so will break that functionality.

Note also that the **Protect** method's **Contents** parameter defaults to **True**, so you don't have to explicitly specify that, although you can for clarity.